# using winston daily rotate without adding datePattern to file name

Tags: node.js, winston

in my nodejs logging i am using winston daily rotate file module and it works very well, however i have a question about file naming: is that possible to not have datePattern in the current file name but adding it once it got daily rotated over?

example:

my_log.log  ----- current one

my_log_2017-10-18.log -----yesterday

my_log_2017-10-17.log ----- the day before yesterday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to daily rotate logs using Winston except the first day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853157/how-to-daily-rotate-logs-using-winston-except-the-first-day)